# Can't properly connect to an external server with PhpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am currently using a host that allows me to store things in a database. I had previously been able to access it through MySQL workbench, but I found that PhpMyAdmin has a better feel to it than Workbench, so I installed it instead.

I had done some research and found that you could connect to an external server by changing the host/info in the file config.inc.php. I had done this, as seen below:

```
$i++;

/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'REDACTED';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'REDACTED';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'REDACTED';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
```

When I try to load it up through Xampp however it gives me this:

> ## Error
>
> SQL query: {REDACTED}
>
> SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4';
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> 1115 - Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'

It appears that when it loads up, something tells the Query to change the character-set, and when it does this, it puts out an error. I tried restarting Xampp, changing it back to UTF-8 as well as making sure everything was properly updated.

Whenever I change the values(The REDACTED's) back to default it works again. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version does not support that character set, I believe it was 5.5.3 that introduced it. You should upgrade your mysql or downgrade phpmyadmin.

The error is then quite clear: there is set a certain character, but your mysql version does not support it, and therefore does not know about it.

According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html :

```
utf8mb4 is a superset of utf8
```

upgrade mysql or downgrade phpmyadmin